# Prevent Postback for DropDown for first value in asp.net webform

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have  simple webform with search and other filter.

Search is triggered when user click on the Search Button and filter is trigger based on dropdown change.

**CODE**

```
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server" placeholder="SEARCH" CssClass="form-control search-text"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" CssClass="btn search-btn" />
    </div>


<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 ">
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddCategory" CssClass="form-control" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddCategory_SelectedIndexChanged"  runat="server"  DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="ID" >
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="rfvdd" runat="server" ErrorMessage=""  ControlToValidate="ddCategory" InitialValue="0" ValidationGroup="ddCategory">
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
</div>
```

**CODE BEHIND**

```
String strSql = "SELECT ID, Name FROM  Category ORDER BY Name ASC";
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds = DataProvider.Connect_Select(strSql);
ddCategory.DataSource = ds;
ddCategory.DataBind();
ddCategory.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("CATEGORY", "0"));
```

Using code i as 0 value to Category in `ddCategory` and i dont want to trigger postback when user select Category as an option in `ddCategory` dropdown.

At present when even i select a value postback happens event if it is the first value in the dropdown `Category` with value `0`

How can i avoid such postback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a JavaScript function to make sure no postback happens when the user selects the "Category" entry. This can look like this:

```
function onCategoryChange() {
  var value = $("#<%= ddCategory.ClientID %> option:selected").val(); // use the ClientID from the ddCategory dropdown
  if (value == "0") // this is the value for the "Category" entry
    return false; 
  else {
    __doPostBack('<%= ddCategory.ClientID %>', value);
  }
}
```

You also have to adopt your `DropDownList` so that the JavaScript function gets called. Therefore you add a `onchange` attribute like this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddCategory"
                  CssClass="form-control"
                  AutoPostBack="true"
                  OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddCategory_SelectedIndexChanged"
                  runat="server"
                  DataTextField="Name"
                  DataValueField="ID"
                  onchange="return onCategoryChange();">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

P.S.: Note that I used jQuery to select the selected option in the category dropdown field. If you don't have jQuery available, you have to adopt the selected option selection to use plain JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks JS approach works. Not sure if why required field validator is not working may be it works when associated with Submit Button. Anyways thanks i will use JavaScript approach as i cant spend any more time on this.